# Define new bracket style that works with \big and co?

Tags: brackets

How to define new brackets that work in conjunction with `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, etc? For example, if I do `\newcommand\laangle{\langle|}`, then `\big` is going to affect only the `\langle`-part in `\big\laangle` as well as `\big{\laangle}`. Is it possible to define `\laangle` as `\langle|` in such a way that `\big\laangle` visually results in `\big\langle\big|`?

Comment: these are defined by the font, not by TeX, although you could define a macro that made it easy to type `\bigl\langle\bigl|` (note it should be `\bigl` not `\big` or you will lose the math open spacing implied by `\langle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that will *only* work with the various `\big` commands, as it relies on their internal definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\laangle{\langle\middle|}
\newcommand\raangle{|\middle\rangle}

\[
\bigl\laangle  \frac1n \bigr\raangle  \qquad
\Bigl\laangle  \frac1n \Bigr\raangle  \qquad
\biggl\laangle \frac1n \biggr\raangle \qquad
\Biggl\laangle \frac1n \Biggr\raangle
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This works great for all the brackets I use, thank you :) Clever solution; as far as I understand, you define the inner brackets to be middle elements, so that they are sized like `\bigm`, `\Bigm`, etc.

Comment: Btw. it's no problem that they only work for the various `\big` commands, this reduces my work to two definitions per bracket, instead of my previous method, which defines every bracket for every size.

Comment: Yep, the `\big` commands put their contents between `\left...\right`, so the `\middle` will properly size the second element. Unfortunately, those commands do use the same internal macro for left and right delimiters (note the `\middle` is always on the second delimiter). Perhaps a generalized solution would work if this were redefined.

Comment: How can we reduce the horizontal space between \langle | and \rangle | ?